# Is my LU Factorization Incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, lu-decomposition

I have the following matrix I am trying to decompose into it's respective $L$ and $U$ parts for $A = LU$.

So I have $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 4 && 3 \\ 0 && -10 && -5 \\ 0 && -8 && -4 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc|cccccc}
1 && 4 && 3 && && 1 && 0  && 1\\ 
0 && -10 && -5 && && 0 && 1 && 0\\ 
0 && -8 && -4 && && 0 && 0 && 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

I notice that column $1$ is fine, and I need to make $R_3 C_2 = 0$ to achieve the upper triangle matrix on the left and the lower triangle matrix on the right.

So I do: $R_3 \longrightarrow -\frac{5}{4} R_3 + R_2$

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc|cccccc}
1 && 4 && 3 &&  && 1 && 0  && 1\\ 
0 && -10 && -5 &&  && 0 && 1 && 0\\ 
0 && 0 && 0 &&  && 0 && 1 && -5/4
\end{array}
\right]
$$

However, the answer key is telling me the answer is:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc|cccccc}
1 && 4 && 3 &&  && 1 && 0  && 1\\ 
0 && -10 && -5 &&  && 0 && 1 && 0\\ 
0 && -8 && -4 &&  && 0 && 4/5 && 1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: It is easy to verify if this is correct or not. Just compute $LU$ and verify is this is equal to $A$.